# Notation: Why Ω for the based loop functor?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, notation, loop-spaces

This is just a question about notation - probably useless, but it's always baffled me:

*Why was $\Omega$ chosen to denote the based loop functor?*

I once heard someone speculate: "It's because $\Omega$ looks like... *a loop*?"

Is it really as simple as that? (If so, clever!) Can anyone verify and/or know more?

Thanks in advance!

(PS.
I originally asked this question [on StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2248121/notation-why-%CE%A9-for-the-based-loop-functor), but it seems Overflow is a better fit.)

Comment: Wouldn't surprise me. Note also that $\Delta$ is used to denote the simplex category and objects therein, and $\Lambda$ a horn of a simplex.

Comment: It would help if we knew *who* chose that notation, and *when* they did.  I don't know the answer.  After poking around on MathSciNet, the earliest use of $\Omega$ for a loop space I can come up with is (MR0055683) G. Whitehead, "On the Freudenthal theorems" (Annals, 1953).  He actually uses "$\Omega^{n+1}$" for what we call $\Omega S^{n+1}$.

Comment: Of course, I should have checked Serre first: he uses $\Omega_x$ for "based loops of $X$ at $x$" in his 1951 Annals paper about the Serre spectral sequence, for instance.

Comment: The way he talks about it in the first paragraph makes me suspect he took the notation from Morse and/or Hurewicz, but I can't follow those references.

Comment: Morse's book "The Calculus of Variations in the Large" from 1934 uses $\Omega$ for the based loops in a manifold.